# Is there any way to call a destroy method that isn't on the Object in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-java-config

I'm creating a queue of files so we can clean them up on destruction.

```
@Bean( name = TMP_FILES )
@Scope( WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION )
static Queue<File> tmpFiles() {
    return new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>(  );
}
```

What I'm wondering is if there's a way I can make a custom destroy method that's not on the class (that will iterate over these and call delete), another static in my `@Configuration`

Comment: If the method is not on a class, where do you think it should be, given that Java only allow method implementations on classes (ignoring default methods on interfaces)?

Comment: Write your own `Queue` class that delegates to this `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` and further implements a method. You can then either annotate that method with `@PreDestroy` or use its name with `destroyMethod` in `@Bean`.

Comment: @Andreas maybe a way to provide the location within the `@Configuration`, or on another bean `com.foo.MyConfig.destroy` maybe it could be defined with SpEL

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis yeah I'm just seeing if there's a way around that, as this seemed too simple for that.

Comment: No, a bean's destroy method works on the corresponding bean itself. Another option is to create another bean in which you inject `tmpFiles` and have that bean manage the destruction.